# Datagrid value binding to an external ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, combobox

I would like to be able to set the value of the current selected row>cell of a `DataGrid` through an external `ComboBox`.

The code I have is working fine on the setter part, **but can't make the `ComboBox` selected value matching the grid value**... seems I am missing a mapping.

Here is what I have:

1- The Datagrid is bound to a `ObservableCollection<Object>`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, AncestorLevel=2},
          Path=SelectedCounterparty, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

2- The `ObservableCollection<Object>` has a property that I should bind to the Combobox (i.e. the Combobox selected item should take that property value):

```
public CurrenciesEnum Ccy
{
    get { return this._ccy; }
    set
    {   
        if (value != this._ccy) 
        {
            this._ccy = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Ccy");
        }
    }
}
```

3- The Combobox source is an enum:

```
public enum CurrenciesEnum { USD, JPY, HKD, EUR, AUD, NZD };
```

4- The current mapping of the Combobox:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Currencies" MethodName="GetNames" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="ConfigManager:CurrenciesEnum" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Currencies}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Ccy, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**What works:** Able to set the "Ccy" property of the current selected item in the grid through the ComboBox.

**What doesn't:** The ComboBox selected item isn't the matching the current selected item in the grid when changing line (and defaulting to USD or the previously selected value), in other words doesn't seem to be bound properly. Any idea on how to fix this

Comment: why the `SelectedValuePath="{Binding Ccy}"` - just try with `SelectedItem`

Comment: you have both `_spc1Ccy` and _ccy 'backing' the same property

Comment: Corrected both remarks. Just typo as I was testing at the same time. The issue is still the same though

Comment: Instead of `List<object>`, use `ObservableCollection<object>`.

Comment: It was actually already an ObservableCollection<Object>, sorry. Have updated the post. Actually I've found the solution (needed a converter) but not allowed to answer yet, will do in few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue.

This was due to the fact that a ComboBox SelectedItems gives back a string ([CSharp Corner: Binding an Enum to a ComboBox](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/binding-an-enum-to-a-combobox/)) where I was binding to the Enum itself.

So to fix the issue I have defined a converter and used it in my binding:

**Converter:**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(Object))]
public class StringToCurrencyEnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {   
        if (value!=null)
        {
            CurrenciesEnum enumValue = (CurrenciesEnum)value;
            return enumValue;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string temp = ((CurrenciesEnum) value).ToString();
            return temp;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Updated Binding:**

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:StringToCurrencyEnumConverter x:Key="StringToCcyEnum" />
</Grid.Resources>

<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Currencies}}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Spc1Ccy, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToCcyEnum}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have bound `ObservalbeCollection<MyDataGridItem> MyDataGridItems` to the datagrid `ItemsSource` property.

Define a property in the `view model` to bind the `SeletedItem` of the datagrid as follows.

```cs
private MyDataGridItem SelectedDataGridRow;

public MyDataGridItem SelectedDataGridRow
{
    get
    {
        return selectedDataGridRow;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedDataGridRow= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDataGridRow");
    }
}
```

Let's say the the property which you are gonna bind to the DataGrid column is `MyColumn` (MyColumn is a property of `MyDataGridItem` class)

Then in your setter method of the Ccy property, set the MyColumn property as follows.

```cs
 public CurrenciesEnum Ccy
 {
    get { return this._ccy; }
    set
    { 
        if (value != this._ccy) 
        {
            this._ccy = value;

            //This is the code you need to implement

                this.MyDataGridItems
                    .Where(item=> item== this.SelectedDataGridRow)
                    .First()
                    .MyColumn = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("Ccy");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Actually found another way, cf. my answer to the question